# How to use background service with KSOAP2 that active when there is connect to server?

Tags: android, sql-server, android-ksoap2

I'm working in my project which has a SQLLIT and interacts with `SQL-server`. In my server I want to know: how can I make a service that listens to my `sqllite` table and checks if there is a new record in any of tables? It's passing this record to server using ksoap2.

Also I need to make my service first check if there is a network available or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your SQLite table changes from an activity (somehow requires some sort of user interaction). So i would suggest the following approach:

1. Create a SQLite table with some listeners that are called whenever the table performs any CRUD operation.

   ```
   public class YourSqliteTable {

   private TableListener listener;

   public void insert(Object urData){

   //insert data here to sqlite table
   // call the listener
     listener.onInsert(urData);

   }
   }

   public interface TableListener{

   public void onInsert(Object tableRow);

   }
   ```

2.create a service that handles soap messages and listens to SQLite table:

```
public class SoapService extend Service implements TableListener{

     private HanlderThread soapThread;
     private Handler       soapHandler;

     public void onCreate(){

        soapThread = new HandlerThread("handler_thread");
        soapThread.start();
        soapHandler = new Handler(soapThread.getLooper){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch(msg.what){
                case(1)://send data to server
                HttpTransportSE transporter    = new HttpTransportSE(Server.TIGA_SERVER_IP
                                                         + SOAP_URL);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope sEnv = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                try { 
                    request.addProperty("data", msg.obj);
                    sEnv.dotNet = true;
                    sEnv.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    transporter.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, sEnv);
                    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) sEnv.getResponse();
                    return response.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                  transporter.reset();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

     }

     @Override
     public void onInsert(Object tableRow){

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 1;
        msg.obj  = tableRow;
        soapHandler.sendMessage(msg);
     }

}
```

1. Bind the user activity to the SoapService and when binding is established (onServiceConnected is called) register the service as a listener to the SQLite table.
2. Checking if internet connection is available can be done as :

   public boolean isNetworkOn(){

   ```
   ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) 
                                getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNet = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   if(activeNet == null)
       return false;

   if(activeNet.isAvailable() && activeNet.isConnected())
       return true;

   return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: sorry i late i will do what u do and i will tell u if i get any axceptions